# jQuery Datatables, TableTools Plugin Buttons are not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, datatable

I have downloaded Jquery's dataTables.tableTools.js and dataTables.buttons.js along with the matching styles. I have confirmed that links are correct.

The issue is that my datatable works just fine, but when I add a button for exporting to csv it does not show up. The rest of the table is perfect, there are no errors according to firebug. It just will not display the button. I am using [Jquery's guide to tableTool buttons](https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv) to do my script.
Here is mine:

```
$("#table").DataTable({
  buttons: [ 
    'csv'
  ]
 });
```

Can any one help me? I see a ton of similar questions but they all are using flash. This should just use HTML5. Am I missing something this is my first time using tableTools.

Comment: I also tried with the options extend: 'csv',
            text: 'Copy all data',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    search: 'none

Comment: Put quotes around #table

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy that code I wrote it, and it has quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i usually generate my datatables, maybe it helps.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "dom": 'lf T<"clear"> rtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": ["print"]
            },...
```

This  should automatically take the tools when you have the bundle imported.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datatables").Include(
                    "~/Content/DataTables-x.xx.x/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
                    "~/Content/DataTables-x.xx.x/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatables").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables-x.xx.x/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables-x.xx.x/dataTables.tableTools.js"));

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/datatables")
```

Make sure you have the correct swf in your Content/Datatables/swf folder.

Comment: If I am correct there is no need for flash, unless targeting older browsers. My example should work with no flash. According to the dataTables.net.

Comment: this did lead me to the answer! I wasn't rendering the button. You need one more line for my example. That is to append the button to the data table. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't it just the dom property? What did i miss?

Comment: No, it was that it needs to be appended even if you set the dom prop. Like this: table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( $('.col-sm-6:eq(0)', table.table().container() ) );